# bower registration has missing metadata

Tags: node.js, bower

I can't figure this out! I'm trying to register a package to bower but it keeps complaining about missing metadata entries and when I install the package it doesn't have the right files.

#### shell

`bower register xxx [git]`

```
bower invalid-meta  xxx is missing "main" entry in bower.json
bower invalid-meta  xxx is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
```

#### bower.json

```
{
  "name": "xxx-client",
  "version": "0.0.9",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/xxx/xxx-client",
  "authors": [
    "Myself <myself@gmail.com>"
  ],
  "description": "client for xxx server",
  "keywords": [
    "javascript",
    "xxx",
    "xxx-client",
    "js",
    "node.js"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist",
  "dependencies": {
    "superagent": "~0.21.0"
  },
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "public",
    "bin",
    "routes",
    "views",
    "app.js",
    "LICENSE",
    "*.md",
    "*.json",
    "gulpfile.js",
    "bower_components",
    "public/bower",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

Comment: ok well this is really stupid, but it worked when I registered from a different directory than the source code...

Comment: Those are warnings which can be ignored.